# Subversion: How can I move a working copy under a new one, its parent?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I checked out:

```
http://svn.example.com/department/project1
```

Under my working copy, I have defined many --set-depth options to avoid downloading too much, and I have a few scrap files that are not committed, nor I want them to be, but I want to keep them (and yes, they are backed up by other means).

My 'project1' working copy has only one '.svn' directory' at 'project1/.svn', as expected.

Now I want to checkout:

```
http://svn.example.com/department
```

and move my 'project1' working copy (with all its local configuration and local files) under my 'department' working copy.  Is it possible to integrate 'project1/.svn' into 'department/.svn' locally?